# Classes based on React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New, new, new to React. Downloaded the following sample of setState method in classes that extend React.Component. It works fine, but I'm not understanding why no object needs to be instantiated for App, since each user could be in a different location...

I somehow thought index.js would need:

```
const app = new App()
```

Is there a reason for this?

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor ( props ) {
        super ( props );
        this.state={ latitude: null};

        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
            ( postion ) => {
                this.setState( {latitude: postion.coords.latitude })
            },
            ( error ) => console.log ( error )
        );
    }

    render () {


        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <p>
                        LATITUDE: {this.state.latitude}
                    </p>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The ReactDOM part is needed to actually render html. Otherwise react would output very little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you do instanciate objects everytime you use a React component. You can translate `const app = new App()` by using `<App/>` in your code. In your case, one instance is in the ReactDOM.render function.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply! Just to clarify, is the <App /> reference actually instantiating App under the covers - is this explained in the React docum?

Comment: ...or maybe another way of asking my question is - for each reference to the App class, will I be instantiating a new object?

Comment: Yes, you instanciate a new object for each reference. But in general, you just use the <App/> component one time by convention. But if you create another class component, by example a class called "Timer" that you use  several times in your <App/>. Each <Timer/> will be a unique instance with its own state and methods (that's why you use "this").

Comment: My confusion was that, in vanilla JS, I would have to explicitly instantiate each object.